# Executing stored procedure with custom table datatype

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a method that returns `DataTable A` from SQL Server. `DataTable A` is passed to another method that opens a SQL Server connection, sets a parameter value, and executes the procedure to insert the rows from `DataTable A` into the new SQL Server table..

The problem I have is that when I run `ExecuteNonScalar`, I get a return value of 0, and my records are not inserted and I don't understand why. I do not get an error.

I have checked that `DataTable A` has data by displaying it in a `DataGridView`.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new SqlCommand("InsertRequests", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRequestImportDataType", data).TypeName = "dbo.NewRequestImportDataType";
        returnString = command.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
return returnString;
```

Edit: here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertRequests]
    @NewRequestImportDataType NewRequestImportDataType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [tbl RequestData] (Request, EnterReqDt, Comp, Cust, OrderNum, InvoiceNum, Type, TrackNum, DelIssue, Comped, CompType, homeTel, WorkTel, custname, requestByName, AcctName, tele, Comments, ARStatus, email, Uname)  
        SELECT * 
        FROM @NewRequestImportDataType 
END
```

Comment: When a command calls a StoredProcedure you should set the CommandType property accordingly

Comment: Show the stored proc code.

Comment: Also, don't use `AddWithValue`, and you don't need to specify the `TypeName`.

Comment: I have added  `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: @ZoharPeled an exception is thrown stating the opposite of what you said in Visual Studio. Unless my syntax is incorrect, but when I use `add()` it tells me that `add()` is deprecated

Comment: @Steve I believe you had the answer.. Simply adding the commandType and now 39,947 records returned. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerJames, it's true that `AddWithValue` replaces the old version of `Add` that takes a string and an object. But there are other overloads of `Add` you could use, and some argue that [`AddWithValue` is evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). You could, for instance, construct a `SqlParameter` directly, set its `SqlDbType =  SqlDbType.Structured` explicitly, set its `TypeName` as you're already doing, and then call the version of `Add` that takes a `SqlParameter`.

Comment: Use this overload of `Add` instead: `command.Parameters.Add("@NewRequestImportDataType", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = data`. Official documentation claims you must use the `TypeName` property but experience says otherwise - I've never used it myself and have been working with table valued parameters since 2008 version.